# IronPython basic program

Tags: .net, ironpython

Got this code in C#:

```
using System;

public class Listener{
   public static void Main(){
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world...");
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Tried to translate it to IronPython and compile it by `ipy pyc.py /main:Listener.py Listener.py /target:exe`:

```
from System import *

class Listener:
    def Main(self):
        Console.WriteLine("Listening")
        Console.ReadLine()
```

When I try to run it by `ipy` or directly the exe, nothing happens.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have/require a main method (by convention entry point).

You just have to call the Main-method at the end of your .py if you want to run it.

```
Listener().Main()
```

Another way to do this is to check if you are the primary/first python file to run. This allows you to create modules which can be used/imported or run standalone:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Listener().Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from System import *

class Listener:
  def Main(self):
    Console.WriteLine("Listening")
    Console.ReadLine()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Listener().Main()
```

or, more Pythonic

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  raw_input('Listening')
```